# Qt Quick - How to use setContextProperties()

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I want to try out `rootContext()->setContextProperties()` instead of `rootContext()->setContextProperty()` because I read it is more efficient to bundle the properties instead of setting them X-times by yourself. Unfortunately I cannot find any good ressource on how to use it.

So e.g. in the `main.cpp` I have

```
ClassA a;
ClassB b;
```

Normally I would go for

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(&a, "classA");
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(&b, "classB");
```

So how can you syntactically correct sum this up and form it into a `QVector<QQmlContext::PropertyPair>`? The docs are really bare for this one.

A small example would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This struct contains a property name and a property value. You can add multiple properties as a collection.

```
QSharedPointer<QQmlApplicationEngine> m_engine;
QQmlContext* m_ctxt;
m_engine->clearComponentCache();
m_engine.reset(new QQmlApplicationEngine, &QObject::deleteLater);
m_ctxt = m_engine->rootContext();
m_ctxt->setParent(m_engine.get());
QVector<QQmlContext::PropertyPair> qmlProperties;  

qmlProperties.push_back(QQmlContext::PropertyPair{"classA", QVariant::fromValue(objectA)});         

qmlProperties.push_back(QQmlContext::PropertyPair{"classB", QVariant::fromValue(objectB)});
    //add other context properties
m_ctxt->setContextProperties(qmlProperties);
m_engine->load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you. ```QVariant::fromValue(objectA)``` was the missing thing.